# How to start Matlab profiler

Tags: matlab, profiler

I switched to Matlab 2012b (from 2011a), but fail to find out how to start the profiler gui in the new matlab gui.

Comment: Do you mean `profile on`?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I missed the "gui" part. Your suggestion is definitely the correct one :].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The GUI option is still there, in the editor tab:

[image]

You will be able to specify input parameters once the function has crashed ;)

Comment: They ribbonized it! Nooos!

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: You can always start in -nodesktop mode :)

Comment: @Rody Oldenhuis if you don't like that, you still can create your own shortcuts, launching `profile on` / `profile viewer` on a good old "command shortcuts panel", which would be available even if ribbon itself is hidden.

Comment: @Igor: yup, definitely my preference. But I think it's good to at least learn where everything is located now -- know thy enemy :p

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK, this should still work:

```
profile viewer
```

while we're at it, these tweaks should still work, too:

```
profile -memory on
setpref('profiler', 'showJitLines', true);
```

I don't have the opportunity to check, but you mean to say that R2012 doesn't have the little button on the top anymore?

Comment: Yes, since R2012b, the menu has changed a lot. Mostly for the better, IMHO, but it can be frustrating if you don't find certain functionality anymore. +1 for the command-line option.